# Why does the reactivity of VUE 3 CompositionAPI not work?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Please tell me why reactivity between unrelated components does not work:

**ModalsController.js**:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
export const useModal = (init = false)=>{
  const isShowModal = ref(init);
  const openModal = () => {
    isShowModal.value = true;
  };
  
  const closeModal = () => {
    isShowModal.value = false;
  };
  return {
    isShowModal, openModal, closeModal
  }
}
```

Header.vue:

```html
<template>
    
  <button @click="openModal">OpenModal</button>
 {{isShowModal}} 
    <button @click="closeModal">CloseModal</button>
</template>

<script setup>

import {useModal} from "./ModalsController.js";
const { isShowModal,openModal,closeModal } = useModal();
  
  

</script>
```

Modal.vue:

```html
<template>
 
  <div v-if="isShowModal"> Modal window </div>
  
</template>

<script setup>
 import {useModal} from "./ModalsController.js";
const {isShowModal} = useModal();

</script>
```

And everything works if I create a simple variable instead of a function like this:

ModalsController.js:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
export const isShowModal = ref(false);
```

and accordingly, I change it in the header. But this is very inconvenient because there are way more functions (switching, etc.)
Thank you all in advance for your help. I put the code in the Playground for the test:

1. [Not a working (func)](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IHJlZiB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcbiAgXG4gIFxuaW1wb3J0IEhlYWRlciBmcm9tIFwiLi9IZWFkZXIudnVlXCI7ICBcbmltcG9ydCBNb2RhbCBmcm9tIFwiLi9Nb2RhbC52dWVcIjsgIFxuICBcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuXG48dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gPEhlYWRlci8+XG4gPE1vZGFsLz5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiaW1wb3J0LW1hcC5qc29uIjoie1xuICBcImltcG9ydHNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidnVlXCI6IFwiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZmMudnVlanMub3JnL3Z1ZS5ydW50aW1lLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsIk1vZGFsc0NvbnRyb2xsZXIuanMiOiJpbXBvcnQgeyByZWYgfSBmcm9tICd2dWUnO1xuZXhwb3J0IGNvbnN0IHVzZU1vZGFsID0gKGluaXQgPSBmYWxzZSk9PntcbiAgY29uc3QgaXNTaG93TW9kYWwgPSByZWYoaW5pdCk7XG4gIGNvbnN0IG9wZW5Nb2RhbCA9ICgpID0+IHtcbiAgICBpc1Nob3dNb2RhbC52YWx1ZSA9IHRydWU7XG4gIH07XG4gIFxuICBjb25zdCBjbG9zZU1vZGFsID0gKCkgPT4ge1xuICAgIGlzU2hvd01vZGFsLnZhbHVlID0gZmFsc2U7XG4gIH07XG4gIHJldHVybiB7XG4gICAgaXNTaG93TW9kYWwsIG9wZW5Nb2RhbCwgY2xvc2VNb2RhbFxuICB9XG59IiwiSGVhZGVyLnZ1ZSI6Ijx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgICBcbiAgPGJ1dHRvbiBAY2xpY2s9XCJvcGVuTW9kYWxcIj5PcGVuTW9kYWw8L2J1dHRvbj5cbiB7e2lzU2hvd01vZGFsfX0gXG4gICAgPGJ1dHRvbiBAY2xpY2s9XCJjbG9zZU1vZGFsXCI+Q2xvc2VNb2RhbDwvYnV0dG9uPlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT5cblxuPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cblxuaW1wb3J0IHt1c2VNb2RhbH0gZnJvbSBcIi4vTW9kYWxzQ29udHJvbGxlci5qc1wiO1xuY29uc3QgeyBpc1Nob3dNb2RhbCxvcGVuTW9kYWwsY2xvc2VNb2RhbCB9ID0gdXNlTW9kYWwoKTtcbiAgXG4gIFxuXG48L3NjcmlwdD4iLCJNb2RhbC52dWUiOiI8dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gXG4gIDxkaXYgdi1pZj1cImlzU2hvd01vZGFsXCI+IE1vZGFsIHdpbmRvdyA8L2Rpdj5cbiAgXG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuXG48c2NyaXB0IHNldHVwPlxuIGltcG9ydCB7dXNlTW9kYWx9IGZyb20gXCIuL01vZGFsc0NvbnRyb2xsZXIuanNcIjtcbmNvbnN0IHtpc1Nob3dNb2RhbH0gPSB1c2VNb2RhbCgpO1xuXG48L3NjcmlwdD4ifQ==)
2. [working (simple var)](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `useModal()` creates a new `ref()` every time it's called. Each of your components calls `useModal()` to get the `isShowModal` `ref`, but each `ref` is a newly created one independent from each other.

To share the `ref`s between components, move the `ref` creation outside of the `useModal` function definition:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';

const isShowModal = ref(false); 

export const useModal = (init = false) => {
  // const isShowModal = ref(init); ❌ move this outside function
  ⋮
}
```

[demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)